# WPF Combobox display entity name in dropdown instead of DisplayMemberPath

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have the following combobox:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbBonusType" 
          DisplayMemberPath="BonusTypeName"  
          SelectedValuePath="ID" Width="150" Margin="10,0,0,0"                  
          SelectionChanged="cbBonusType_SelectionChanged"/>
```

When running:
When selecting an item, the combobox shows exactly the right string.
But while the droppbox is open, the named displayed in the droppbox are **all** set to the name of the entity: "CaSaMa.WPF.UI.Competiotion.BonusType".

Why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: Where is your Itemssource and how does it look like?

Comment: What is the type of `BonusTypeName` property? string? `CaSaMa.WPF.UI.Competiotion.BonusType`?

Comment: Are you overwriting the `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` anywhere?

Comment: BonusTypeName is a filed in the database. It is a property on an Entity object.
There is no more code than what I mentioned. I am not overwriting anything anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Best bet would be override the ToString on your object - that would give you a consistent display across your application.

hope that helps!

Just re-read your question - think I got the wrong end of the stick.. What you can do is set the ItemTemplate on the control instead like this;

```
      <ComboBox Name="cbBonusType" 
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DisplayTemplate}"
      SelectedValuePath="ID" Width="150" Margin="10,0,0,0"                  
      SelectionChanged="cbBonusType_SelectionChanged"/>
```

then create the template like this

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DisplayTemplate"
          DataType="{x:Type <YOURTYPE>}">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding BonusTypeName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

its a known problem and this is the workaround sadly!

hope it helps.. this time! :)

edit : updated code just incase anyone else would like to use it!

ste.

Comment: WOW!!! Thank you so so so much!!! This works perfectly!!!
If you can edit your answer, maybe you can change in the template so it says "{x:Type Combobox}" instead of BonusType, in case someone else wants to use the same solution. :-)
Again thank you sooo much. :-)
Keren

Comment: @Keren No Problem, glad to help - the Datatype tag just allows you to see the properties for the type when it comes to binding. Since this answer seemed to fix it - could you mark it as Accepted please?

Answer (score 0):

Its way easier than this...in XAML:

```
<ComboBoxItem Content="This Value" Tag="This Value"/>
```

Then in code behind:

```
GetValue=ComboBoxName.selecteditem.tag.tostring()
```

GetValue will be "This Value" instead of 
"System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: This Value"